# How to Add Space or Padding to Terminal Output?

Tags: zsh, prompt, terminal-emulator, oh-my-zsh, kitty

I don't really know what would be responsible for this. I would bet on my terminal emulator itself (mine is Kitty), but it might be a Zsh (or Oh My Zsh) or Powerlevel10k responsibility.

Anyways, what I would like to do is add some space between my input line and the beginning of my output. And also add some padding just so my Powelevel10k input line is aligned vertically with my output. Padding on the right-hand side would be great as well.

[image: Screenshot of what I have in mind for my terminal prompt]

Answer (score 1):

> I would bet on my terminal emulator itself

No, it shouldn't be that. The terminal emulator's job is to precisely execute the instructions it receives. It's not in the position to override anything and insert a blank where it wasn't asked to, or skip one where it was asked to have one.

(By the way, you can in no time start up another terminal emulator to check the behavior there and thus tell for 100% certainity whether it's Kitty inserting those blank lines or not.)

> but it might be a Zsh (or Oh My Zsh) or Powerlevel10k responsibility

Yes.

The one at the bottom *could* be that the previous utility (`git status` in this case) prints an empty line there, but knowing `git` it's not the case here.

> Anyways, what I would like to do is add some space between my input line and the beginning of my output.

It's the shell that could theoretically do this. I don't know whether any shell out there supports this feature out of the box, or you'd need to patch one.

> And also add some padding just so my Powelevel10k input line is aligned vertically with my output.

Indenting the output of utilities is pretty much hopeless. Forget it. (There are some limited possibilies, e.g. left/right margin support of some terminal emulators, but many apps that format their output to the screen width will break if you try to use that. Alternatively, you'd have to convince each and every utility out there to indent all of its lines, again, hopeless.)

Interestingly, though, you phrased your question as "so my Powelevel10k input line is aligned vertically with my output" rather than "so my output is aligned vertically with my Powelevel10k input line"; surely, you can modify your prompt not to indent and then it'll align with the output of your utilities.

Comment: Don't terminal emulators provide some sort of hook between output from programs and outputs printed so we could process every program's output, instead of going through each and every one of them individually, like you said?

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro No. The terminal doesn't even know whether what it's showing is an interactive shell or not. It could as well be a text-based adventure game for all it cares.